# Does $(n+1)^x-n^x$ go to $\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for $x>1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does $(n+1)^x-n^x$ go to $\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for $x>1$? I suspect it does from plots, but I want to use the ratio test to prove that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(cn-vn^x)
\end{align}
converges for $c,v>0$ and $x>1$. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about: as $n \to \infty$, we have
\begin{align}
(n+1)^x &= n^x\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^x \ge n^x\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)
\qquad\text{[Bernoulli's inequality]}
\cr
(n+1)^x - n^x &\ge n^x+xn^{x-1}-n^x = xn^{x-1}
\cr
(n+1)^x - n^x & \to +\infty\qquad\text{[$x > 1$]}
\end{align}

Comment: Accepted this one because it's quite elegant.

Answer (score 5):

I am not seeing how the ratio test would help per se.

We can see however, that $d(n^x)/dn = (x-1)n^{x-1}$. This goes to $\infty$ with $n$ for $x>1$, and furthermore, is an increasing function. So

$$(n+1)x-n^x \ = \ \int^{n+1}_n(x-1)m^{x-1}dm \ \ge \ 1 \times (x-1)n^{x-1}$$

and as the term on the right goes to $\infty$ as $n$ does, then so does $(n+1)^x-n^x$.

Comment: The idea looks right but there's a small mistake $d(n^x)/dn=x n^{x-1}$, which needs to go to the fundamental theorem of calculus and resulting inequality as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$(n+1)^x-n^x=n^{x-1} \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^x-1}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Now
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{n-1}= \infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^x-1}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{(1+z)^x-1}{z}= \frac{d}{dz} (1+z)^x  |_{z=0}=x
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the ratio test for $$a_n=(n+1)^x-n^x$$
$$R=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+2)^x-(n+1)^x } {(n+1)^x-n^x }=\frac{\left(\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^x-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^x\right) n^x } {\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^x-1\right) n^x  }$$
Let $\epsilon=\frac 1n$ to make
$$R=\frac{(1+2 \epsilon )^x-(1+\epsilon )^x }{(1+\epsilon )^x-1 }=1+(x-1)\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)$$
$$R\sim1+\frac {x-1} n > 1 \qquad \text{if} \qquad x>1 \implies \text{divergence}$$